# Install ubuntu on x205ta

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I tried *install Ubuntu* on Asus x205ta. I tried numerous dist Ubuntu, I found this comp want 64-bit OS + 32.bit installer, just this way I can start process installation.

I copied file `bootie32.efi` in directory `UEFI/BOOT`.

But during installation, Wifi on laptop didn't work and then appear following error :

```
grub-efi-ia32' package failed to install into /target/. without the grub boot loader, the installed system will not boot
```

Comment: I solved my problem by connecting my smartphone as a modem. I did complete the installation successfully, but now the wi-fi of my laptop doesn't work.  I even can't figure out why and can't find what is model my wi-fi.

Comment: Please make the WiFi issue a separate post.